# React Routes element component not showing

Tags: reactjs

I am following a course that used the following way to route, all the paths/routes work fine except the Favorite path it does show any component the Fav component only has a div that says Fav but it won't show. using any other component for example "Checkout" works fine.

```
return (
     <Router>
              <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} favItems={fav.fav_items}/>
            
            <Routes>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/cart"
                element={
                  <Cart
                    cart={cart}
                    handleUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty}
                    handleRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
                    handleEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
                  />
                }
              />
    
              <Route
                path="/checkout"
                element={
                  <Checkout 
                  cart={cart} 
                  order={order}
                  onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout}
                  error={errorMessage}
                  />
                }
              />
    
              <Route
                path="/favourite"
                element={
                  <Fav/>
                }
              />
            </Routes>
    
          
        </Router>

  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the code but the Grid that I had prevented it from showing.